# android bluetooth chat newbie

Tags: android, bluetooth

I just now bought a HTC Wildfire S and wanted to test the bluetooth chat example given in android dev site. What I am doing is in eclipse I am opening a new android project->Create project from existing sample->BluetoothChatapp.Then I clicked on run and the emulator got launched, I have also connected my htc wildfire to the system and enabled USB debugging.When I clicked on the Bluetooth chat icon on the emulator, it says Bluetooth not found.Kindly help me on this, as this is my very first try on android.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll to the bottom of this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html. Your answer awaits.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator does not support Bluetooth, and yes it's a little bit annoying. You will need two phones to properly test the Bluetooth chat example. So to use your phone instead the guide is found at:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html